# Python: Remove numbers at the beginning of a string

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have some strings like this:

```
string1 = "123.123.This is a string some other numbers"
string2 = "1. This is a string some numbers"
string3 = "12-3-12.This is a string 123"
string4 = "123-12This is a string 1234"
```

I need to remove these numbers from the beginning of the string. I tried `strip[start: end]` method but because of the irregular format of the string I cant use it? any suggestions?

Comment: Should the *punctuation* be removed too?

Comment: And what should happen with the whitespace, after having removed the digits and punctuation? Perhaps you could add some expected *output* to your question?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can remove all digits, dots, dashes and spaces from the start using [`str.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip):

```
string1.lstrip('0123456789.- ')
```

The argument to `str.strip()` is treated as a *set*, e.g. any character at the start of the string that is a member of that set is removed until the string no longer starts with such characters.

Demo:

```
>>> samples = """\
... 123.123.This is a string some other numbers
... 1. This is a string some numbers
... 12-3-12.This is a string 123
... 123-12This is a string 1234
... """.splitlines()
>>> for sample in samples:
...     print 'From: {!r}\nTo:   {!r}\n'.format(
...         sample, sample.lstrip('0123456789.- '))
...
From: '123.123.This is a string some other numbers'
To:   'This is a string some other numbers'

From: '1. This is a string some numbers'
To:   'This is a string some numbers'

From: '12-3-12.This is a string 123'
To:   'This is a string 123'

From: '123-12This is a string 1234'
To:   'This is a string 1234'
```

Comment: I didn't mention that also there are numbers inside strings that I don't want to remove, this will remove all?

Comment: @EstinaEsitna: this removes theses *only from the start*. Not from anywhere else.

Comment: can you tell me why regex does not replace in `lstrip()`. I am trying `string1.lstrip(r'(\d+(.|-|\s)?)+')`

Comment: @RohanAmrute: why would it? It doesn't accept regular expressions, it accepts a set of individual characters. Use the `re` module for regular expressions.

Comment: @RohanAmrute: `import re` then `re.sub(r'^[\d.-]+\s*', '', string1)`.

Comment: `re.sub()` will substitute the numbers inside the string also and not only present in front of it. So it will not help in this case.

Comment: @RohanAmrute: no it won't, because I anchored the expression to the start with `^`.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost the same as @MartijnPieters' answer but we could use constants from `string` module if there are a lot of punctuation and whitespace characters to strip on top of digits:

```
import string
nonalpha = string.digits + string.punctuation + string.whitespace
out = some_string.lstrip(nonalpha)
```

So for the given sample:

```
for sample in [string1, string2, string3, string4]:
    print('From: {!r}\nTo:   {!r}\n'.format(sample, sample.lstrip(nonalpha)))
```

Output:

```
From: '123.123.This is a string some other numbers'
To:   'This is a string some other numbers'

From: '1. This is a string some numbers'
To:   'This is a string some numbers'

From: '12-3-12.This is a string 123'
To:   'This is a string 123'

From: '123-12This is a string 1234'
To:   'This is a string 1234'
```