# How to remove beginning-digits only in R

Tags: r, regex

I have some strings with digits and alpha characters in them. Some of the digits are important, but the ones at the beginning of the string (and only these) are unimportant. This is due to a peculiarity in how email addresses are stored. So the best example is:

`x<-'12345johndoe23@gmail.com'`
Should be transformed to `johndoe23@gmail.com`

unfortunately there are no spaces. I have tried `gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', x)` but this removes all numbers, not just the beginning-ones

Edit: I have found some solutions in other languages: [Python: Remove numbers at the beginning of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201490/python-remove-numbers-at-the-beginning-of-a-string)

Comment: Use `^[[:digit:]]+` - `^` asserts position at start of string.

Comment: that works - thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/G6JRBm/1)

```
^[[:digit:]]+
```

`^` Asserts position at the start of the string

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
x<-'12345johndoe23@gmail.com'
gsub('^[[:digit:]]+', '', x) #added ^ as begin of string
```

Answer (score 2):

Another  regex is :

```
sub('^\\d+','',x)
```